# How to update on a client-side single div rendered by Django?

Tags: javascript, django, fetch-api

I have a `<div>` on a page dynamically rendered by Django on the server side.
On a client side I use **js** with the `fetch()` method to make a **get request** which updates a database (likes on posts).
Then I just wish to refresh that `<div>` with new data.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AJAX to send [Request](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) to server and update the HTML elements upon [Response](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_response.asp).